# Blackberry 9800 Simulator Crashing When Launching Browser

Tags: blackberry, jvm, blackberry-simulator, jvm-crash, blackberry-torch

The Blackberry 9800 simulator is crashing when launching the browser, throwing

> JVM Error 104: Uncaught
>   IllegalStateException.

This is a clean install of the simulator with no 3rd party applications installed to it. I strictly wanted to use it for testing web applications. All other applications on the device seem to work without error.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssXZs.png]

Answer (score 8):

I managed to get it working.

1. Exit the Simulator (if running)
2. Go to c:\program files\Research In
   Motion
3. Right click BlackBerry Smartphone
   Simulators 6.0.0
4. Click Properties
5. Select the Security Tab
6. Click The Edit button
7. Click the Add... button
8. Add your user account to with "Full
   control" checked
9. Click the OK button

Launch the simulator and all should be well.

Answer (score 2):

This solution didn't work for me, but reinstalling as described here did.
http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-Development/9800-Simulator-Browser-crashes-JVM-Error-104/m-p/594666

Answer (score 1):

right click, and launch like administrator (W7)