# Blackberry 9800 Simulator crashing with ClassCastException when viewing a website

Tags: html, blackberry, blackberry-simulator

I have been developing a website but am finding it is crashing the simulator throwing a "ClassCastException".

[image]

Can anyone tell me what causes this?

I found the the following 
http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/17970/Known_issues_1007761_11.jsp
although I wouldn't have suspected this would be the cause?

Also found some other questions on SO but these relate to an IllegalStateException, and the solutions haven't helped.
[Blackberry 9800 Simulator Crashing When Launching Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639649/blackberry-9800-simulator-crashing-when-launching-browser)

Comment: Have you tried using a different simulator (one that also uses the web-kit browser) ?

Comment: @user470184 At present no, although did try it with an earlier version of the Blackberry simulator which didn't crash

Comment: I assume you've tried navigating to other websites on the simulator? Id try re-installing the simulator. That looks to me to be a problem with your browser. The error looks to be a native JVM error rather than a problem with your site.

Comment: Some more info on jvm error 104 - http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/JVM-Error-104/td-p/36987. A quick read points to a problem with a native app, not a website.

Comment: @user470184 I can navigate to other sites ok without it crashing, yep have been searching myself and not found anything specific to websites

Comment: Try opening the blackberry log (Alt L Alt G Alt L Alt G, on the simulated device keyboard), maybe you can find something useful after this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went to try getting the logs and found the site had started working. What it was causing the exception I can't be sure could have possibly been `console.log` commands left in.